# Pandas create flag if any condition fails

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas dataframe (actually has 5M rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'opn1': [20180301, 20180401, 20180501, 20180601, 20180701, 20180801, 20180901, 20181001, 20181101, 20181201],
                   'opn2': [20180401, 20180501, 20180601, 20180701, 20180801, 20180901, 20181001, 20181101, 20181201, 20190101],
                   'opn3': [20180501, 20180601, 20180701, 20180801, 20180901, 20181001, 20181101, 20181201, 20190101, 20190201],
                   'opn4': [20180601, 20180701, 20180801, 20180901, 20181001, 20181101, 20181201, 20190101, 20190201, 20190301],
                   'opn5': [20180701, 20180801, 20180901, 20181001, 20181101, 20181201, 20190101, 20190201, 20190301, 20190401],
                   'cls1': [0, 20180520, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'cls2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 20181031, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'cls3': [0, 0, 20180725, 0, 20180701, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'cls4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20190101, 0, 0, 0],
                   'cls5': [0, 20180731, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20190510],
                   })
```

My requirement is to create a flag with value as 1 if any of the close dates `cls1..5` is < the corresponding open date `opn1..5`

Example output: for id==2, cls5 < opn5

I want to avoid a loop and run it as fast as possible. There are ~5M rows in my data.

Perhaps `np.where` with a combination of `any`?

Comment: can you add your sample output?

Comment: id 2 and 5 should be flagged as 1

Comment: Using 0 as a missing value seems worse than using NaN. (it saves memory, but will be slower).

Comment: my data already has zeros.

Comment: Do a performance benchmarking to compare the solutions.  My tests using %%timeit shows that my solution is the fastest among the 3 solutions using the sample data (my solution 0.9ms  while other solutions are 1.4ms, 3.x ms).  A bit busy now, so can't show you the benchmarking outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`np.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) with `axis=0`. First create the condition and then apply it on the relevant columns:

```
cond = lambda i: ((df['cls' + str(i)] != 0) & (df['cls' + str(i)] < df['opn' + str(i)])).values
df['flag'] = np.any([cond(i) for i in range(1,6)], axis=0).astype(int)
```

This will flag the rows with `id=2` and `id=5`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to filter the columns into 2 portions for comparison.  Then use `any` on `axis=1`, as follows:

```
df['flag'] = (  ((df.filter(like='cls').values != 0) & 
                 (df.filter(like='cls').values <  df.filter(like='opn').values)
                )
                .any(axis=1)
                .astype(int)
             )
```

**Result:**

`id` 2 and 5 are flagged.

```
print(df)

   id      opn1      opn2      opn3      opn4      opn5      cls1      cls2      cls3      cls4      cls5  flag
0   1  20180301  20180401  20180501  20180601  20180701         0         0         0         0         0     0
1   2  20180401  20180501  20180601  20180701  20180801  20180520         0         0         0  20180731     1
2   3  20180501  20180601  20180701  20180801  20180901         0         0  20180725         0         0     0
3   4  20180601  20180701  20180801  20180901  20181001         0         0         0         0         0     0
4   5  20180701  20180801  20180901  20181001  20181101         0  20181031  20180701         0         0     1
5   6  20180801  20180901  20181001  20181101  20181201         0         0         0         0         0     0
6   7  20180901  20181001  20181101  20181201  20190101         0         0         0  20190101         0     0
7   8  20181001  20181101  20181201  20190101  20190201         0         0         0         0         0     0
8   9  20181101  20181201  20190101  20190201  20190301         0         0         0         0         0     0
9  10  20181201  20190101  20190201  20190301  20190401         0         0         0         0  20190510     0
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another version where you loop over the possible open and close combinations:

```
df['flag'] = False
for i in range(1,6):
    df['flag'] = df['flag'] | (df[f'cls{i}'] < df[f'opn{i}']) & (df[f'cls{i}'] != 0)
```